# Test FTP locally with WAMP 2.0?

Tags: php, ftp, testing, local, wamp

I have WAMP 2.0 installed and am working on a content management system using PHP and MySQL. Is it possible to use the PHP FTP functions on my local machine, so I can test them?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a remote ftp server or do you have one setup locally?

Comment: I have a remote FTP server, but am just curious if this is possible. I do not know how to set one up locally. Perhaps that should have been my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use PHP's FTP functions from your local machine. If you are wanting to test these functions by connecting to an FTP server on your local machine then you will need to set one up. I believe that there's a [FileZilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/) which would get you up and running with that, but I couldn't testify to it's quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but you need to run an FTP server. Microsoft IIS [used to ship](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323384) with one many years ago - but I'm not sure about current versions - but there are freeware / GPL / shareware [products](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/ftpfiletransfer/tp/aatp_winftpserv.htm) available.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the PHP FTP
>   functions on my local machine

Yes it is. It should be enabled by default in your WAMP installation. You can easily test these functions. The following will connect to an FTP server and print the directory listing:

```
$con = ftp_connect($server) or die("Couldn't connect"); 
ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
ftp_close($con);
```

Comment: Where do I find what my username and server name are? I don't recall setting one up. Since my hostname is localhost, would the server name be ftp.localhost.com?

Comment: Oh. You mean *connect* to a server on your local machine. You will need to install one. Use FileZilla Server: http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server  Then try the code provided and use localhost as the server.

Comment: Thanks, I had just done this, per icio's recommendation below. I am using the port number (?) as the host name and it is working.